# Execute external command in the same screen

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

When executing `:silent !command` (followed by `:redraw!`) the screen goes to the terminal, then it come back to vim.

How can I make it execute in the same screen, without this "blink"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to just execute some command, but don't want to see the output. If so, then just use the function system

```
:call system("g++ myfile.cpp -o output")
```

or whatever command you want to do. However, I would recommend just putting the output in a seperate window, you can use the [QuickRun Plugin](https://github.com/thinca/vim-quickrun) and the just run:

```
:QuickRun bash -src "g++ myfile.cpp -o output"
```

and the result will be in a separate window.

Comment: That's it! The `call system` works as I wanted. Better than `:read`, that requires `> /dev/null`. Interesting plugin btw, thank you!